# How to create view of referenced nodes with fields?

Tags: views, nodes

I have `node reference` field which can take multiple values in it and I want to create a `view` of fields of these referenced nodes.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding node reference field to contextual filter and select "Provide a default argument" in it and select "Content ID from URL". This will do the needful.